# pg_dump Transaction Isolation Level Error

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, transaction-isolation

I'm having a hard time finding a reason/solution for this error.  I'm hoping someone else has seen this and has some direction.  These commands have been successful in the past from this same host. I'm running the pg_dump command in Linux command line and get the following error.  I've tried multiple options for pg_dump and they all fail from this host with the same error message. I've even tried to dump data from different databases within the same host.

- pg_dump (PostgreSQL) 14.9
- PostgreSQL engine version 14.6

I've included a few of the basic commands I've tried:

```bash
pg_dump -d dbname -s -n schemaName -h host -p 5432 -U adminID > outputfile
pg_dump dbname -h host -p 5432 -U adminID -Z0 -j 10 -Fd -f testDeck
pg_dump -d dbname -a -t tableName -h host -p 5432 -U adminID > outputfile
```

The error I get every time:

```
pg_dump: error: query failed: ERROR:  SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL must be called before any query
pg_dump: error: query was: SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ, READ ONLY
```

Comment: For some reason having pg_hint_plan enabled is what was causing my issue.  One I removed it, I was able to successfully use pg_dump again.  I am unsure why but thought I'd post a solution.

Comment: Yes, please write an answer. Any extension that somehow starts a transaction automatically would be a problem.

Comment: My solution was to just run this command:  drop extension pg_hint_plan .  After that executed successfully, I could run my original pg_dump commands without error.